# Наложение тени на картинку при прокрутке горизонтальным скроллом

Tags: css, css3, изображения, img

Столкнулся с проблемой наложения тени на картинку при добавлении горизонтальной прокрутки. Тень позиционируется абсолютно, если заменить на `relative`, то она пропадает.
Как можно наложить тень чтобы она перемещалась вместе с картинкой при использовании горизонтальной прокрутки?

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.slide {
  width: 1000px;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.slide::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(253, 187, 45, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 193, 195, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='slide'>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" />
  </div>
  <div class='slide'>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" />
  </div>
  <div class='slide'>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" />
  </div>
  <div class='slide'>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" />
  </div>
  <div class='slide'>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" />
  </div>
</div>
```

***P.S.***

При нажатии выполнить, немного пролистайте вниз, там Вы увидите второй скролл который крутит картики

Comment: такое можно попробовать сделать одним лишь бэкграундом, без псевдоэлементов

Comment: @StrangerintheQ хорошая идея, а куда наложить этот бэкграунд ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а для

```
.slide {
position: relative 
}
```

не вариант?)

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.slide::before {
  content: '';
position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(253, 187, 45, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 193, 195, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='slide'>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" />
  </div>
  <div class='slide'>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" />
  </div>
  <div class='slide'>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" />
  </div>
  <div class='slide'>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" />
  </div>
  <div class='slide'>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 4):

Можно подобное сделать при помощи одного лишь background, без псевдо элементов:

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.slide {
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(0, rgba(253, 187, 45, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 193, 195, 0) 100%),
              var(--url);
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='slide' style='--url:url(https://picsum.photos/id/231/200/300)'></div>
  <div class='slide' style='--url:url(https://picsum.photos/id/232/200/300)'></div>
  <div class='slide' style='--url:url(https://picsum.photos/id/233/200/300)'></div>
  <div class='slide' style='--url:url(https://picsum.photos/id/234/200/300)'></div>
  <div class='slide' style='--url:url(https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300)'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Интересный вариант, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Stranger in the Q действительно интересный вариант. Просто и со вкусом.